# Is there a site like plaintextoffenders.com that shames companies that force insecure passwords?

Tags: web-application, passwords, password-policy, disclosure

I recently came across http://plaintextoffenders.com/ and I liked the idea. I wondered if there was a similar site that shames websites that force insecure passwords?

I personally have a list of a few websites that force insecure passwords (no puntuation/symbols allowed or a silly maximum length) and would like to submit them to such a site if it exists.

Perhaps if it doesn't exist, I could even make one myself...

Comment: but what's wrong with plaintextoffenders?

Answer (score 5):

You can just submit them to Plaintext Offenders. They accept any type of password-based idiocy.

Answer (score 0):

As Polynomial said, you can just submit them into PTO. I haven't seen many original sites alike that so making your own wouldn't be too much of a bad idea. However, there is always the problem of actually raising a better site than something already popular. What will yours have that theirs doesn't? Good luck if you do voyage on to making a similar website.

Comment: Yeah, I checked with PTO and polynomial is right. They also say that they are working on a JSON feed which sounds good. I think I'll just submit to them.